# IP Logging with Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, iptables, logs

I use Ubuntu to host my web sites. I would like to generate a log of every IP address that "touches" my Ubuntu installation - including ping, port scans, etc, not just http requests. What would be an efficient way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Network packets can be logged using iptables [`LOG`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbDD) target. To avoid logging every packet arriving to system, you can use [`limit`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbBI) and/or [`conntrack`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbAO) module(s).

`LOG` target writes messages in kernel log. *Syslogd* is often configured to write these messages to a log file. These messages can also be viewed with `dmesg`

It is also possible to use [`AUDIT`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html#lbCO) target for logging, in which case logs are written to audit log by *auditd*. When you write a rule with `AUDIT` target, you need to specify audit record type via `--type` option.

#### Example:

1. Accept packet associated with established connections.

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   ```
2. Other packet are logged (with a rate limit). A prefix to be included in log can be set with `--log-prefix` option.

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG \
            --log-prefix "iptables: " --log-level info
   ```

Note that iptables rules are evaluated in order. Processing stops at first matching rule to `ACCEPT` or `DROP` target. `LOG` target does not stop processing.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what my question requested. I had been trying to avoid going to products I had used in the past like nmap and wireshark. As my server is on a separate network with a static IP, the logged file shouldn't be too overwhelming to process.